# Unable to get Window Title using GetGUIThreadInfo

Tags: c++, winapi

I was googling and discovered that the above function is more reliable in retrieving the Window Title Text but it does not work. I get no results; in other words no string of the title is captured.

```
GUITHREADINFO gui;
gui.cbSize = sizeof(gui);
char pStr[1024];

GetGUIThreadInfo pGetGUIThreadInfo;

HMODULE hinstUser = LoadLibrary((LPCTSTR) "user32.dll"); 
pGetGUIThreadInfo = (GetGUIThreadInfo)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("user32.dll")), "GetGUIThreadInfo");
if (pGetGUIThreadInfo(0 , &gui) == 0)
    return NULL;

GetWindowText(gui.hwndFocus, pStr, 1024);
```

But the above code fails. What does work is using the following code

```
HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
GetWindowText(hwnd, pStr, 1024);
```

Comment: How does that even compile?  `GetGUIThreadInfo` is the name of a function, not a type.

Comment: He must have a typedef for it that he didn't include in the code snippet since he's using GetProcAddress.

Comment: Yes thats correct there is a typedef in the .h file that I did not include. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will do what you want if you use `hwndActive` rather than `hwndFocus`.

That said, I can't see what is wrong with using the window returned by `GetForegroundWindow()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I tried the setting that you suggested and it works. Appreciate the reply. Sorry for not including the the typdef in my original source code.

Comment: @victor if this is the answer to your question please mark it as such by placing a green tick next to the answer.